# Clear the items after ContextMenuStrip is shown

Tags: contextmenustrip

I wanted to clear the items just after the ContextMenuStrip is shown. However when I was making the following calls,  ContextMenuStrip didn't show properly in the first place. Any ideas?

```
ContextMenuStrip.Show()
ContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard this thread.

I should handle ContextMenuStrip.Closing event and put ContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear() inside to do the job.

Thanks,